# Delete the data in the Database by date

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have made a simple program, where this program will add the data in the database, the submitted time, and also the expired time (which is add 2 days after submission). However, when the data already in the database and I change the date in the computer as same as the expired time and then when I run the program, the data in the database where suppose to be deleted, is not.

And also is the `Timer` with Interval `1000` (1 second) is will be executed even though we did not run the program?

Basically, I want to delete the data in the database automatically when the expired time is reached. For example: There is a data in the database with expired date and time is January 31st 2015, and when that expired date and time is reached, that data will be deleted automatically from the database.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=../db1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";

    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Interval = 1000;

        _timer.Tick += delegate
        {
            RealTimeTimer();
        };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add();

        this.label2.Text = this.textBox1.Text;

        this.label3.Text = Convert.ToString(UserInformation.Submitted);

        this.label4.Text = Convert.ToString(UserInformation.Expired);
    }

    private void RealTimeTimer()
    {
        UserInformation.Submitted = DateTime.Now;

        if (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))
        {
            Delete();
        }
    }

    private void Add()
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO [Data] ([Description], [SubmittedOn], [ExpiredOn]) VALUES (@Description, @SubmittedOn, @ExpiredOn)";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    UserInformation.Expired = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

                    command.Parameters.Add("@Description", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@Description"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@SubmittedOn", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@SubmittedOn"].Value = Convert.ToString(UserInformation.Submitted);

                    command.Parameters.Add("@ExpiredOn", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@ExpiredOn"].Value = Convert.ToString(UserInformation.Expired);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is an exception: " + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM [Data] WHERE [ExpiredOn] = @ExpiredOn";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@ExpiredOn", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@ExpiredOn"].Value = Convert.ToString(UserInformation.Expired);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is an exception: " + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

class UserInformation
    {
        public static DateTime Submitted
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static DateTime Expired
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Thank you for those who are interesting with this question.

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you so much.

Comment: seems like the timer (or something) ought to pass the new deadline; the date compare should be >= to remove all old ones, not just those which happen to match, and if you are going to do Date compares use Date columns not varchar/string/text.  Strings wont compare like dates do

Comment: @Plutonix As long as the column in the database is of type `date`, `datetime`, or `datetime2` there is no problem having the parameter be a string. In fact, it's preferable to always use strings to avoid conversion due to time zones, etc. But you are right about the `>=` instead of `=`.

Comment: the "date" data saved does not appear to be Date types, but strings (see the Insert).  "09/01/2000" will always evaluate greater than "12/31/2016" because text compares do not work for dates.  There are many issues which need to be debugged

Comment: @Plutonix: I am using `DateTime` data type in the database, and is working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHERE [ExpiredOn] = @ExpiredOn

You know that this will only be true when the two dates match exactly, right?  And the chances that this query runs at the exact second this is true is spectacularly unlikely to happen, right?

Try **>=**

Comment: To add to this, when I delete by date, I go back to the day before at 11:59:59 and delete to the end date at the same time.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you for that @Will. But, is there any way to keep it like real time? Because the data in the database not being deleted even though the date is same with the expired date in the database (only will be deleted when the program runs). I just replace the delete parameter with this: `command.Parameters["@ExpiredOn"].Value = UserInformation.Submitted;` when I am using `>=`, but when I am using `<=` it will be `UserInformation.Expired`. Thank you

Comment: @Yunnan real time?  Not without setting something up in the sql database server.  But then, what's the requirement that it be real time?  Or is there none?  I suspect there is none, and that deleting it whenever you get around to it would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Ehm, okay then @Will. I just want to play around with this automatically delete data in the database with date. There is no specific reason though. Thank you for your answer. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    private void Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM [Data] WHERE [ExpiredOn] <= @ExpiredOn";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiredOn", UserInformation.Expired);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is an exception: " + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you for that @Will. But, is there any way to keep it like real time? Because the data in the database not being deleted even though the date is same with the expired date in the database (only will be deleted when the program runs). I just replace the delete parameter with this: `command.Parameters["@ExpiredOn"].Value = UserInformation.Submitted;` when I am using `>=`, but when I am using `<=` it will be `UserInformation.Expired`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

look at this :

```
if (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))
    {
        //  :-(  I Will never be called...
    }
```

Its on your timer_tick method which will not be called.
How can DateTime.Now be Greater than two days after..?

```
;
```

Let me give you an easy method to do your job. i.e to delete records which are submitted exactly two days before. All you need to do is just let the timer run.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        RealTimeTimer();
    };
}
```

.

```
 private void RealTimeTimer()
{
    Delete();
}
```

.

```
private void Delete()
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "DELETE FROM [Data] WHERE DateAdd('d', 2, [SubmittedOn]) <= Now";
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

By letting the timer run, the db checks itself for records submitted before 2 days exactly and delete them.